# comparing dicts based on key and create a new dict with the missing key, with a 0 value in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have three dicts say `dict_a`, `dict_b` and `dict_c`

```
dict_a={'key1':a, 'key2':b, 'key3':c}
dict_b={'key1':a, 'key2':b, 'key4':d}
dict_c={'key3':c, 'key1':a, 'key5':e}
```

Here the keys that are represented overall are: key1, key2, key3, key4, key5 with their respective values.

What I am looking for is eg., to create a new dict (or keep the dicts) and fill the missing keys in each dict in compare to the overall keys with 0 values and the key e.g,:

```
dict_a={'key1':a, 'key2':b, 'key3':c, 'key4':0, 'key5':0}
dict_b={'key1':a, 'key2':b, 'key3':0, 'key4':d, 'key5':0}
dict_c={'key1':a, 'key2':b, 'key3':c, 'key4':0, 'key5':e}
```

I am experienced in C, and based on my "limited knowledge" in python I would run a nested for-loop with a bunch of if, else statement to solve this, however what I know is python have some tools eg. `zip`, `lamda` etc. to nail this in a simple way. But I don't know how to start and begin, or even if there is a library that can solve this ?

it doesen't matter if I create new dicts with the missing keys or simple replace the existing dict, both are usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a union of your keys and then just create new dictionaries containing all keys that you update with your previous values.

```
all_keys = set(dict_a).union(dict_b, dict_c)
new_dict_a = dict.fromkeys(all_keys, 0)
new_dict_a.update(dict_a)
print(new_dict_a)
# {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'b', 'key3': 'c', 'key4': 0, 'key5': 0}
```

The same for the other dicts:

```
new_dict_b = dict.fromkeys(all_keys, 0)
new_dict_b.update(dict_b)

new_dict_c = dict.fromkeys(all_keys, 0)
new_dict_c.update(dict_c)
```

The `dict.fromkeys` creates a new dictionary containing all the specified keys with a default value (in this case `0`) and then the `update` overwrites the values that were already in the original dictionary.

Comment: oh, did not know `dict.fromkeys`. will have to remember! thanks.

Comment: great, this is exactly what I was looking for. It is good to know these features  (update, union) thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could do this:

```
all_keys = set(dict_a).union(dict_b, dict_c)
default = 0

dct_a = {key: dict_a.get(key, default) for key in all_keys}
print(dct_a) # {'key2': 'b', 'key4': 0, 'key5': 0, 'key1': 'a', 
             #  'key3': 'c'}
```

...and so on for the other dicts.

once you have collected `all_keys` it's just a one-liner to create the new dictionary. `dict.get` is either the value that belongs to the key - if it exists - or `default` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys=set(dict_a).union(dict_b, dict_c)
for a in keys:
   if a not in dict_a.keys():
      dict_a[a]=0
   if a not in dict_b.keys():
      dict_b[a]=0
   if a not in dict_c.keys():
      dict_c[a]=0
```

Using sets to avoid having duplicates, we get all the keys. Now we know all the keys there are. Now we check if any of these keys are not in any of the dicts and if they are not, we add them with the value 0.This will give your desired output